# LibGDX Scene2d: How to add a row to an ImageButton?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I know that I could use ImageTextButton, but for some reason I want to just add a row to an ImageButton, which is a child class of Table.

I try this like that:

```
ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(skin, "style");
Label lb = new Label(text, skin);
btn.row();
btn.add(lb);
```

The label appears not under the image, but right next to it.

Why does `row()` not start a new row, just like in a regular table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [recent LibGDX bug](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4183). I think you can get around it for now by adding an empty cell before adding a new row. Like this:

```
btn.add().row();
```

You may need to use `colspan(2)` on the next item you add to keep it aligned correctly.